# Currency and decimal numbers

Tags: php, numbers, decimal, currency

I am creating a test ecommerce shop but am having problems with two things: 
1) My prices have the dollar sign ($) and not the pound sign (£).
2) My prices are rounded up.

This a screenshot

[image]

From research on the net I found how to add the pound sign using the following code:

```
$<?= '&pound;'. number_format($product['list_price'],2); ?>
```

I had to add &pound as the £ caused and black triangle to appear.

This is the result of adding this code:

[image]

This is not exactly what I wanted. How do I have the price as £19.99? (or other).

This is the entry in the database:

[image]

[image]

Both prices (list_price and prices where entered as £24.99 (prices), and £19.99 using the insert option in phomyadim.

This is the php code relating to the products:

```
<?php require_once 'core/init.php'; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured =1";
$featured = $db->query($sql);
?>
```

Any help to have my currenct formatted to £, and two decimal places wil lbe appreciated.

Comment: Maybe remove the `$` from `$<?= '&pound;'. number_format($product['list_price'],2); ?>`

Comment: The `$` in front of the code you posted (outside the PHP tags) is the currency symbol. Replace it with `£` and that's all you need. Regarding the decimal places, read about [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Or let [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) handle both the amount and the currency (it doesn't work out-of-the-box, it requires proper setup before starting to be useful).

Comment: @axiac this is a problem mainly with his database. Since he's using `decimal` and not set it up correctly, his database will not accept a properly formatted currency. `money_format()` and `number_format()` won't make a difference apart from displaying `.00` when he likely wants to show something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB structure is incorrect, `10,0` allows for 0 decimal places. This can be seen here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f54cd/1

Change the structure to `10,2` to allow 2 decimal places.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1bf0f/1

You can read more about this here,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

The black diamond is an encoding issue, use UTF8.